# Passing data between multiple UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I got a collection view with 2 different sections. I want to tap a cell in one of the sections and pass the text in that cell to a text view, which is in a separate cell in its own section.

This is what I tried so far, but nothing happened. I am trying to send the notes data to another cell. I can print the data when the cell is tapped.

**Updated**: This is the cell with the text view that I want to pass the selected cell data to.

```
// cell that I am trying to passing data to
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "notesView", for: indexPath) as! TestViewCollectionViewCell
    cell.myTextView.text = .....

    return cell
}


// Cell that I am passing data from
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // Cell that I want to send data to 
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "notesView", for: indexPath) as! TestViewCollectionViewCell

        let myNotes = notes[indexPath.row]
        cell.myTextView.text = myNotes.textView
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody even knows what notes is.

Comment: @ El Tomato, thanks for your reply. notes is an array of string, that I am using to populate the collection view.

Comment: @IamWayne You should use `cellForItem` instead of `dequeueReusableCell`.

Comment: @trungduc Thanks for your reply, I am new to swift and collection view. But I am using cellForItem to display data in the collection view cells. Just don't know how to pass data from one cell to another cell in a separate section.

Comment: you should dequeueReusableCell with indexPath of the cell you want to put the text into, not the cell that you tapped.

Comment: @koropok thanks for your reply, I updated my answer. Maybe that will help, clarify what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can correct that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        //First get your selected cell
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestViewCollectionViewCell {

            //Now get selected cell text here
            //update your section two array with new values
            //Reload your collection view.


        } else {
            // Error indexPath is not on screen: this should never happen.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution resolve my issues. Thank you very much!